# How do I export Wordpress users in a xml file?

Tags: mysql, xml, wordpress, export

I am trying to move a Wordpress site to a new system. For this, all the posts, comments and users need to be exported to xml files.

Exporting posts and feedback is already given in Wordpress export menus.

I know, I can export users directly from database.

I want to know, is there any way other than that someone tried?

Comment: "...is there any way other than that someone tried?" Tried xml or other formats with phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

Use phpmyadmin, the MySQL database admin tool, which should be available on your webhost or you can install it yourself: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

Export in CSV, XML, SQL, etc.

Comment: Boss, OP needs to export the WP Users, not the DB.

Comment: Charley, OP can export just the users from the DB in xml if he wants to.

Comment: He **doesn't** wanna export the DB. He just needs to export the **users** in a WP Understandable XML. Hope you get it. :)

Comment: You're not reading my answer or my comments: "...can export just the users from the DB in xml if he wants to" with phpmyadmin.

Comment: I know, I read, I understood. That XML file will **not be readable** by Wordpress importer. :) Hope **you** understand!